# Got ParserError when compiling in Truffle but works fine in remixIDE, dont know why?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Here is the piece of code given below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract counterContract {
    uint256 public tokenCounter;

    function setCounter() public {
        unchecked {
            tokenCounter += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this code using `truffle compile` it gives me the below error:

```
Error parsing /home/lenovo/deepak/solidity/contracts/counterContract.sol: ParsedContract.sol:8:19: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'
        unchecked {
                  ^
Compilation failed. See above.
```

but the same code works perfectly in remixIDE.

How do I resolve this issue?